# Is it pointless to receive a parameter/argument and do nothing with it?

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm learning python from a textbook. This code is for the game Tic-Tac-Toe.

The full source code for the problem:
http://pastebin.com/Tf4KQpnk

**The following function confuses me:**

```
def human_move(board, human):
    """ Get human move."""
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Where will you move? (0 - 8): ", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal: print "\nThat square is already taken. Choose another.\n"
    print "Fine..."
    return move
```

I do not know why the function receives 'human' parameter. It appears to do nothing with it.

```
def human_move(board, human):
```

How would I know to send 'human' to this function if I were to write this game from scratch? Because I can't see why it is sent to this function if it isn't used or returned.

Comment: @aIKid Are you sure? i don't see it? `legal = legal_moves(board)`

Comment: It is normally pointless, but my guess is that you will be modifying this code soon to play a game in which whose turn it is matters. The instructor has left this parameter in to minimize api churn betweeen the different games.

Answer (score 1):

The answer: it depends. In your example it seems useless to me, but I haven't checked it in depth.

If you create a function to be used only from your code, it is in fact useless.

```
def calculate_money(bank_name, my_dog_name):
    return Bank(bank_name).money

money = calculate_money('Deutsche bank', 'Ralph')
```

But if you are working with some kind of API/Contract, the callbacks you specify might accept arguments that are not needed for a certain implementation, but for some others, are necessary.

For instance, imagine that the following function is used in some kind of framework, and you want the framework to show a pop up when the operation is finished. It could look something like this:

```
def my_cool_callback(names, accounts, context):
    # do something blablab
    context.show_message('operation finished')
```

But what if you don't really need the context object in your callback? you have to speficy it anyway for the signature to match... You can't call it pointless because that parameter is used sometimes.

**EDIT**

Another situation in which it could be useful, would be to loop through a list of functions that have almost the same signature. In that case could be ok also to have extra arguments as "garbage placeholders". Let's say all your functions need 3 arguments in general, but one needs only 2.